# Can you do math operations with inline style values or use SASS to do math operations with inline CSS?

Tags: php, css, sass, inline, nette

Due to my php code (nette framework) being dynamic, I use some inline styling.

`<div id="parent" style="height:{$place->getHeight()}px; ">`

This creates a problem for me as I need the children divs to retake this parent div's height and divide it by 3.

Is there any way to do this with inline styling? E.g.:

`<div id="child" style="height:({$place->getHeight()}/3)px; ">`

Basically can you do something like `style="height:(9/3)px"`

Or is there some SASS / SCSS alternative to acomplish this?

Thank you for your time and wisdom.

Comment: I think this should do it `<div id="child" style="height:<?php $place->getHeight()/3; ?>px; ">`

Comment: Why not use JS?

Comment: CSS has a [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function, see if that works

Comment: didnt occur to me to use calc() inline. It worked. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it works. Could you maybe post your solution for others to find?

Comment: <div id="child" style="height:calc({$place->getHeight()}px / 3)">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U should use `calc()`.

```
style="height: calc(<?=$place->getHeight()?>/3)px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
div{
  width:<?=$width?>;
}
</styles>
```

Why do you need it? JS fits better for frontend.You cant measure client width/height via backend

Comment: Assuming JS is not disabled. Also, there's no JS in that code.